# Storing item from listbox to textbox on button click

Tags: asp.net

I have a textbox "txtName" listbox "listNames" and button "btn_Add". Now i want to populate the textbox with the name selected from the listbox on button click.

I am using asp.net and c#. please help.

Comment: Please post some code that you have tried..

Comment: protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtName.Text = listNames.SelectedItem.Text;
    }

Comment: how you load listbox items? is it from code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do as below

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if(!IsPostBack)
     {
        //load listbox items here 
     }
}
```

if you load data on page load, in every post back your listbox will load again and again, you will lost the selection. Do as above to load data only first time page load. now you can get the list box selected items in button click event.

Answer (score 0):

But this in your button.

```
txtName.Text = listNames.SelectedItem.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this on your code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     listNames.Items.Add("listboxItemValue1","Listbox Item Text 1");
     listNames.Items.Add("listboxItemValue2","Listbox Item Text 2");
} 

protected void btn_Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     txtName.Text = listNames.SelectedItem.Text;
}
```

and this on your Asp,net page

```
<asp:button ID="btn_Add" runat=server" OnClick="btn_Add_Click" />
```

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

On code behind button click event.

```
 txtText.Text = drpDwn.SelectedValue; // This is for ID
 txtText.Text = drpDwn.SelectedItem.Text; //This is for Text
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
textbox.Text= listbox.SelectedItem.ToString();
```